# Multiple instances of the same class, how to await a method of one instance and pass that value to another instance

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm working on a 2019 Advent of Code challenge (day 7), so bonus if you've done it before. Basically part of the challenge requires you to be running 5 "computers" which are processing a made-up programming language. Each computer gives an output that needs to be passed to the next computer to process, and it'll keep doing this in a cycle until a certain stop condition is met.

I have made a class that generates a "computer" and have 5 instances of it running concurrently. Each instance needs to await receiving output from the the computer it's connected to. Ignore what it's being assigned to, but here's the code for the relevant line:

`this.code[this.code[i + 1]] = await ampA.output()`

Here's the output method if you're curious:

```
output(output, value1) {
        output = value1
        return output
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that this is *calling* ampA.output(), so basically it's calling the method without giving it any arguments, which is not correct. What I want it to do is wait for ampA to arrive at it's next output, and set the variable equal to that output. Is there a way to do this? Am I even in the ballpark of doing this correct? I'm relatively new to coding, and async/await is a bit out of my depth, so it's possible this is a very incorrect approach. Any help is appreciated, and let me know if more clarification about the situation is needed!

Comment: If you're new to coding, this is a pretty complex application to start on.

Comment: That `output` method makes no sense to me. It just returns one of its parameters.

Comment: Assigning `output = value1` has no effect. The function might just as well be `return value1;`

Comment: I realized after I posted that that looked dumb and redundant, it's a relic of the way I had the code previously, ignoring the output = value1, I put this as it's own function because of wanting to have a way to await specifically the action of returning output.

Comment: oh, and yes it is a bit challenging, but you can't grow without doing things that are above your level :)

Comment: You need to learn to walk before you can run.

Comment: that's true, but generally speaking is what I'm trying to do possible, and do you have any advice on what that would look like generally? I'm kinda regretting mentioning the beginner thing, I think that kinda distracted from the question, my bad.

Comment: It's not really clear what's going on, but I suspect what you need is for `ampA` to perform a callback to the object that needs its output when it's generated, rather than awaiting it.

Comment: Thanks! After looking up callbacks, I think that actually helps, sometimes just having the terminology can go a long way.